# Video is not playing on UIView when I try to add UIView element programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

The video is playing when I use `UIView` elements as an IBOutlet from `Main.storyboard`
But video is not playing when I create `UIView` elements programmatically.

Here is the code with `IBOutlets`(the one which is working)

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class TestViewController: UIViewController {

    private var player: AVPlayer!

    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundVideoOutlet: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var contentVideoOutlet: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        backgroundVideoOutlet.backgroundColor = .clear
        view.addSubview(backgroundVideoOutlet)
        backgroundVideoOutlet.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        backgroundVideoOutlet.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        backgroundVideoOutlet.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        backgroundVideoOutlet.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        backgroundVideoOutlet.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        backgroundVideoOutlet.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor).isActive = true

        contentVideoOutlet.backgroundColor = .clear
        view.addSubview(contentVideoOutlet)
        contentVideoOutlet.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentVideoOutlet.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        contentVideoOutlet.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        contentVideoOutlet.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        contentVideoOutlet.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        contentVideoOutlet.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor).isActive = true

        let pathClouds  = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "clouds", ofType: "mp4")!)
        player = AVPlayer(url: pathClouds)

        let newLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        newLayer.frame = self.backgroundVideoOutlet.frame
        self.backgroundVideoOutlet.layer.addSublayer(newLayer)
        newLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill

        player.play()
        player.actionAtItemEnd = .none
    }  
}
```

Here is the code adding ui view elements programmatically(The one which is video not playing. Can you fix below one please)

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var player: AVPlayer!

    lazy var backgroundVideoViewOutlet : UIView =
        {
            let myUiView = UIView()
            return myUiView
    }()

    lazy var contentViewOutlet : UIView =
        {
            let myUiView = UIView()
            return myUiView
    }()

    //var backgroundVideoViewOutlet = UIView()
    //var contentViewOutlet = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        backgroundVideoViewOutlet.backgroundColor = .clear
        view.addSubview(backgroundVideoViewOutlet)
        backgroundVideoViewOutlet.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        backgroundVideoViewOutlet.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        backgroundVideoViewOutlet.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        backgroundVideoViewOutlet.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        backgroundVideoViewOutlet.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        backgroundVideoViewOutlet.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor).isActive = true

        contentViewOutlet.backgroundColor = .clear
        view.addSubview(contentViewOutlet)
        contentViewOutlet.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentViewOutlet.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        contentViewOutlet.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        contentViewOutlet.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        contentViewOutlet.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        contentViewOutlet.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor).isActive = true

        let pathClouds  = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "clouds", ofType: "mp4")!)
        player = AVPlayer(url: pathClouds)

        let newLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        newLayer.frame = self.backgroundVideoViewOutlet.frame
        self.backgroundVideoViewOutlet.layer.addSublayer(newLayer)
        newLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill

        player.play()
        player.actionAtItemEnd = .none
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before getting the frame of `backgroundVideoOutlet` call `view.layoutIfNeeded()` after adding constraints. `view` is the super view of `backgroundVideoOutlet`

```
view.layoutIfNeeded()
newLayer.frame = self.backgroundVideoOutlet.frame
```

Sh_Khan's Answer wont work. Because `newLayer` is a local variable.

Comment: Dear @iOsDev thanks for the solution. Can you explain .layoutIfNeeded() method  little bit please? When should I use this method?

Comment: When you add constraints programmatically, it takes some time to make the changes. If you want to get the updated bounds/frame immediately you can ask the view to change its layout immediately based on the constraints added. As I've mentioned in the answer, add that line before `newLayer.frame = self.backgroundVideoOutlet.frame`

Answer (score 1):

With programmatically constraints it's too late to use frame of a view

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    newLayer.frame = self.backgroundVideoViewOutlet.bounds
}
```

Also if you have outlets don't create constraints , do it in IB